# Calculate multi-layer coil inductance

Tags: inductor, inductance, coil

I tried to calculate the inductance of an existing multi-layer air core. Since it is covered in some kind of insulating tape I cannot see the coil form or the actual extent of the coil.

Some data:

- Measured inductance: 1416 mH
- Coil dimensions: OD 255 mm, ID 213 mm, length 38 mm
- Wire thickness 0.51 mm, + insulation approx. 0.57 mm (AWG24)
- 1380 turns, wire length 1 km, DC resistance 87 Ω

If I plug in these values into Coil64, it reports an inductance of about 0.7 H, only half of the measured value. What did I miss?

[image]

Comment: So, you can't tell if the coil is wound in two layers (or more) --> makes a significant difference.

Comment: @Andy Coil64 reports 27 layers. I would have to ask the lab guy but I believe it to be a credible number.

Comment: Can't you just match the inductance and DCR and be mostly good for your app?

Comment: Since the coil is in close vicinity to a STM, maybe some of the steel tubes couple to the coil altering its inductance. I will try to take another reading with the coil detached.

Comment: Using Nagaoka's formula as described in "Soft Ferrites", pg 348, I get 0.73 H for a length of 30 mm, 0.68 H for a length of 38 mm (you say the length is 38 mm in your text, 30 mm in the screen grab for Coil64).